# How to multiply two matrices of different sizes

Tags: java, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a simple encryption algorithm, so I need to multiply two matrices:

This is the first:

```
86  65  76  76
69  45  71  82
65  78  68  69
```

This is the second:

```
13  9   3   5
2   1   4   6
4   6   2   7
8   5   4   1
```

According to this [page](https://matrix.reshish.com/es/multiplication.php) with which I work, the result should be:

```
2160    1675    974 1428
1927    1502    857 1194
1825    1416    919 1338
```

Here I leave the code that does not work:

```
public class encriptar {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double[][] encriptador = new double[4][4];
    double[][] mensaje = new double[4][3];
    double[][] resultado = new double[4][3];

    encriptador[0][0] = 13;
    encriptador[0][1] = 9;
    encriptador[0][2] = 3;
    encriptador[0][3] = 5;
    encriptador[1][0] = 2;
    encriptador[1][1] = 1;
    encriptador[1][2] = 4;
    encriptador[1][3] = 6;
    encriptador[2][0] = 4;
    encriptador[2][1] = 6;
    encriptador[2][2] = 2;
    encriptador[2][3] = 7;
    encriptador[3][0] = 8;
    encriptador[3][1] = 5;
    encriptador[3][2] = 4;
    encriptador[3][3] = 1;

    mensaje[0][0] = 86;
    mensaje[1][0] = 65;
    mensaje[2][0] = 76;
    mensaje[3][0] = 76;
    mensaje[0][1] = 69;
    mensaje[1][1] = 45;
    mensaje[2][1] = 71;
    mensaje[3][1] = 82;
    mensaje[0][2] = 65;
    mensaje[1][2] = 78;
    mensaje[2][2] = 68;
    mensaje[3][2] = 69;

    resultado = multiplicarMatrizes(encriptador, mensaje);

    imprimirMatriz(resultado);

}

public static double[][] multiplicarMatrizes(double[][] llave, double[][] mensaje) {
    double[][] resultado = new double[llave.length][mensaje[0].length];
    if (llave.length == llave[0].length && mensaje.length == llave.length) {
        for (int k = 0; k < llave.length; k++) {
            for (int mc = 0; mc < mensaje.length; mc++) {
                for (int lf = 0; lf < mensaje.length; lf++) {
                    resultado[lf][k] += mensaje[k][mc] * llave[mc][lf];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}

public static void imprimirMatriz(double[][] matriz) {
    for (int i = 0; i < matriz[0].length; i++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < matriz.length; l++) {
            System.out.print(matriz[l][i] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
}
```

Apparently in the count of the variables, at some point, a variable does not match the size of a matrix but I have not been able to solve it.

Comment: try with double loop

Comment: you can check to multiply matrix online... this is simple math

Comment: type `multiply matrix site:stackoverflow.com` in Google search...

Comment: 1) https://rubberduckdebugging.com/, 2) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication, 3) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm, 4) If you are getting an exception, you should include the stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution similar to what you are trying to do, you can use it if you wish. Your problem stems from the fact that you are confused with your dimensions.

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int r1 = 3, c1 = 4;
    int r2 = 4, c2 = 4;
    int[][] firstMatrix = { {x, x, x, x}, {x, x, x, x}, {x, x, x, x} };
    int[][] secondMatrix = { {x, x, x, x}, {x, x, x, x}, {x, x, x, x}, {x, x, x, x} };

    // Mutliplying Two matrices
    int[][] product = multiplyMatrices(firstMatrix, secondMatrix, r1, c1, c2);

    // Displaying the result
    displayProduct(product);
}

public static int[][] multiplyMatrices(int[][] firstMatrix, int[][] secondMatrix, int r1, int c1, int c2) {
    int[][] product = new int[r1][c2];
    for(int i = 0; i < r1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < c2; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < c1; k++) {
                product[i][j] += firstMatrix[i][k] * secondMatrix[k][j];
            }
        }
    }

    return product;
}

public static void displayProduct(int[][] product) {
    System.out.println("Product of two matrices is: ");
    for(int[] row : product) {
        for (int column : row) {
            System.out.print(column + "    ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

}

In a double array, its [rows][columns] - your output will have 3 rows and 4 columns (as you can see from your website), so your dimensions for result should be resultado[3][4]. Your mensaje matrix should be [3][4] and not [4][3]. I think you can figure out the rest.